# django restframework how to count object and get since(timestamp)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

guys. Im trying to make a notifications system through django restframework, my problem is that i don't know how to get a count of notifications unread and either make a format of the timestamp to since(timestamp) through django restframework because in a normal view i know perfectly how to do that.

Well this is my model:

```
class Notificaciones(models.Model):
   user_a_notificar = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
   on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   komentario = models.OneToOneField(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE,  
   blank=True, related_name="komentario")
   estado = models.ManyToManyField('Evento', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user_a_notificar.username

class Evento(models.Model):
    creadores = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,  
    blank=True, related_name="generadores")
    status = models.CharField(default="Unread", max_length=10)
    mensaje = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    noti_de_evento = models.ForeignKey(Notificaciones, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestampe = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)



def __str__(self):
    return self.mensaje
```

my view:

```
class Notifi(APIView):
    serializer = notizerializer
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        noti = Notificaciones.objects.filter(user_a_notificar=request.user.id)
        lista_noti = Evento.objects.filter(noti_de_evento__in=noti)
        lista_noticount = Evento.objects.filter(noti_de_evento__in=noti, status="Unread").count()
        response = self.serializer(lista_noti, many=True)
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response.data))
```

and finally my serializer:

```
class notizerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Evento
        fields = ('status', 'mensaje', 'event', 'timestampe', 'id')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more detailed answer:

```
from django.utils import timesince

class Notificaciones(models.Model):
    user_a_notificar = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    komentario = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="komentario")
    estado = models.ManyToManyField('Evento', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_a_notificar.username

class Evento(models.Model):
    creadores = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="generadores")
    status = models.CharField(default="Unread", max_length=10)
    mensaje = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    event = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    noti_de_evento = models.ForeignKey(Notificaciones, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestampe = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def unread(self):
        return sum([n.evento_set.filter(status="Unread").count()
                    for n in self.notificaciones_set.all()])

    @property
    def timesince(self):
        return timesince.timesince(self.timestampe)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.mensaje
```

But in serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Evento


class notizerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    unread = serializers.IntegerField()
    timesince = serializers.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        model = Evento
        fields = ('status', 'mensaje', 'event', 'timestampe', 'id', 'unread', 'timesince')
```

Here is my results from my fake data:

```
[{"status": "Unread", "mensaje": "jaja", "event": "1", "timestampe": "2018-11-25T01:48:17.374179Z", "id": 1, "unread": 1, "timesince": "16\u00a0hours, 41\u00a0minutes"}]
```

Comment: LOL! IT WORKS! THANKS MAN! YOU ARE MY HERO!

Comment: because we are just here, i have another doubt :P, i made through ajax a update to the notifications events which update "Unread" to "Read" of all notifications "Unreads" but it takes relatively long time to send, update the notifications box and the bell icon with the unread count and i guess that is because i send the "read" update directly to the database instead of the apirest, if you ask for, i would make a update to show you how did i make it. my question is how can i do that through the apirest?

Comment: Can you create another question? it is difficult to read comments when they get long. Maybe  comment here when you create the question so I can know which one is.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my two cents:

this is a `model` so you can get an idea of how to get `unread` events:

```
class Notificaciones(models.Model):
    user_a_notificar = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    komentario = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, related_name="komentario")
    estado = models.ManyToManyField('Evento', blank=True)

    @property
    def unread(self):
        return self.evento_set.filter(status="Unread").count()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_a_notificar.username
```

with your same `serializer` and view but really in your view you are returning a serializer for `Evento` instead of `Notificaciones`.

In order to get `since(timestamp)` it is the same idea, just create a property that will calculate that. Then in both cases you can add the property of the model to your serializer.

Comment: --"with your same serializer and view but really in your view you are returning a serializer for Evento instead of Notificaciones", That is exactly what i wanna do, i wanna get the events in the notifications box through the apirest but i don't know how to pass a "count" and the timesince, to be specific i dont know how to pass anything else through the apirest than one value, in this case this one:"response = self.serializer(lista_noti, many=True)", i tried it with a dict but it does not work

Comment: Suppose i do that, how do i get the return in the apirest?

Comment: I don't understand exactly your models. In `Django` you have implicit names created for you when you create `ForeignKeys`. For ex, in your case from `Evento` you can access to `notificaciones_set.all()` which are all the notifications related to that event. And from `Notificaciones` you can access to `evento_set` which are all the events related to that Notification. That being said, from `Evento` you can get `notificaciones_set`. I will post my new models and serializers in another answer